# Iterate through array and call data function from loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The follow should return 3 different results depending on the array value as it iterates through.

I think this question is correct, how can I change it so `data{}` is a function called from my loop and so a new set of data is posted each time? (difference is the array value) I'm not sure how I would do this so that the value matches and changes accordingly.

I have a switch included because my API doesn't like the format of the input so have to change it.

Not even sure this is the best approach so any advice is helpful.

**Input**

```
"ABC, DEF, GHI"
```

**Expected output**

```
Call 1 Data =   {"result":{"u_department":"A B.C","record":"001"}}
Call 2 Data =   {"result":{"u_department":"D E.F","record":"002"}}
Call 3 Data =   {"result":{"u_department":"G H.I","record":"003"}}
```

**Script**

```
var tens = "ABC, DEF, GHI"
console.log(tens);
var letters = tens.split(',').map(string => string.trim());
console.log(letters);
// **** Add function? **** //
//Start Data
var data = {};
//Switch site to change format
var site = {};
switch (letters[0]) {
    case 'ABC':
        site = "A B.C";
        break;

    case 'DEF':
        site = "D E.F";
        break;

    case 'GHI':
        site = "G H.I";
        break;
}
var u_department = site;
data.u_department = u_department;
console.log(u_department)
//End Data
// *********************** //

//Request options
var options = {
    // POST Call, headers etc
    ...
    }
};
//Request function
function sendData(data) {
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    });
    req.write(data);
}
//Try send for each array item:
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    sendData(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps, update a variable and then redo the computation?

Comment: Hi Tony, not quite sure on the placement of where I put the function in the loop. Could you elaborate some more please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `forEach` loop in place of your `for` loop.

```js
letters.forEach(letter => {
  var site;
  var data = {};
  switch (letter) {
    case 'ABC':
      site = "A B.C";
      break;
    case 'DEF':
      site = "D E.F";
      break;
    case 'GHI':
      site = "G H.I";
      break;
  }
  data.u_department = site;
  var options = {
    // POST Call, headers etc
  }
  sendData(data, options);
});

function sendData(data, options) {
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    });
    req.write(data);
}
```

You need to make `options` a parameter to `sendData` rather than accessing it as a global variable, since it's local to the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Thanks Barmar but I still cant get this to work. Could you explain the forEach loop please, is this in replacement of my `for var( i = 0 ...` ?

Comment: Got you! I am getting an error of `Script failed with message: ReferenceError: site is not defined`when I try this way. Ill update my code to reflect the same as im doing

Comment: If `site` isn't defined then `letter` must be something other than `ABC`, `DEF`, or `GHI`.

Comment: `switch(letters)` should be `switch(letter)`

Comment: Don't remove your original code, people need to see what it was before my answer.

Comment: Okay sure, ill update to show progress. Thank you I made that change but now 
`ReferenceError: sendData is not defined` which is right

Comment: Nothing should have changed about `sendData`.

Comment: You need to modify `sendData` to take `options` as a parameter, but I didn't do anything to make it not defined.

Comment: I can see the correct values in the logs but its doesnt look like the api calls are been made for each one. I could call it before and get a response.

Comment: I didn't change how it makes the calls. All I did was add a loop to do each letter the same way your code does one.

Comment: I got it working, I didn't have it nested properly. Excellent!! Thank You